# How can I choose what default code is in a file I create in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there a way to change what code VS Code includes in my file by default? When I create a new .java file, it will start me off with

**public class** name **{**
**}**

however, I would also like it to start me off with the main method inside, as well as a comment at the top that I can use to include a couple of information about the program. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This is a question related to programming. Hence, you might get better answers on Stack Overflow ...

Answer (score 1):

This is not the default behavior of the VS Code. It only gives you an empty file when you first create it. You should first identify which extension does this and then try to change the behavior of that extension.

Besides, including a main method doesn't make sense for all files. Not many files need that.